# eventlistener doesn't execute its function

Tags: actionscript-3, image-gallery

I need to put some thumbnails on the stage. they have different width and I need to get the width after They are loaded.I used the listener to find the width but the function which listener should call doesnt run.

why my code doesn't enter to the function of loadThumbs?

```
function makeScroller():void

{

    for (var item:uint = 0; item < 7; item++ )

    {
        var thisOne:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var blackBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var thisThumb:Sprite = new Sprite();

        var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumbList[item]));
        imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadThumbs);

        function loadThumbs (e:Event):void
        {
            blackBox.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            blackBox.graphics.drawRect(-1,-1,imageLoader.width,imageLoader.height);
            thisOne.addChild(blackBox);
            thisOne.blackBox = blackBox;
            thisOne.x = tsX;
            thisThumb.addChild(imageLoader);
            thisOne.addChild(thisThumb);
            tsX += imageLoader.width;
            scroller.addChild(thisOne);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it run makeScroller()? Try my example first below

Comment: This is why we do not nest functions. loadThumbs function will always refer to the last iteration of thisOne,blackBox,thisThumb,imageLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried a more simplified version of your code without any issues, maybe try this:

NOTE: Best practice is to add the COMPLETE listener BEFORE you call load also...

```
function makeScroller():void
{
    var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedHandler);
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://images.imagecomics.com/c/2012/IMG120350.jpg"));


    function loadedHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("loaded");
    }
}
makeScroller();
```